# Detecting form focus and blur (multiple inputs)

Tags: jquery

I've searched around and haven't found a solution anywhere. Here's the situation.

I have a signup form with multiple inputs all within the form tag. How can I detect when someone focuses on the form and clicks off the form? Note* This is different than individual input focus/blurring. In this case, I want to treat the form as a whole, meaning, the blur state WILL NOT be activated when switching between various input fields within the form itself.

Can this be done? My application needs to detect the user focusing on a form, then sliding down a signupHelper. When the user clicks outside the form, the signupHelper slidesUp.

```
$("document").ready(function() { 

/* DETECT FORM USE */

$('#signupForm form').live( "focus", function(event) {
    if( $('#signupHelper').is(":visible") == false) $('#signupHelper').slideDown();
});

$('#signupForm form').live( "blur", function(event) {
    if( $('#signupHelper').is(":visible") ) $('#signupHelper').slideUp();
});
```

});

```
    <div id="signupForm">

<form class="signupMe">
<table cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
        <td class="step">1</td>
        <td class="content" valign="bottom">
            Choose your username
            <input type="text" name="usernameAttempt">
    </td>

    <tr><td colspan="2" class="vSpace"></td></tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="step">2</td>
        <td class="content" valign="bottom">
            Email Address
            <input type="text" name="usernameAttempt">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2" class="vSpace"></td></tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="step">3</td>
        <td class="content" valign="bottom">
            Password
            <input type="password" name="usernameAttempt">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2" class="vSpace"></td></tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><img align="right" src="/img/signup/signup.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>

</tr><table>
</form>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks,
Mark Anderson

Answer (score 1):

Try [out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gVPp/4/). The key is watching all the right events. This is just a basic example of the functionality.

```
$('form').live('focus click', function(e){
    $('#signuphelper').show();
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop prop so it doesnt reach body
});

$('form :input:last').blur(function(){  // blur of last input in form
    $('#signuphelper').hide();
}); 

$('body').live('click', function(){ // if the event reaches body hide helper
    $('#signuphelper').hide();      
});
```

Comment: On second thought, it only works when the user is on the last form field. Is there a way to make it blur whenever the user clicks out of the form from any input? This is different from changing the second instruction to saying $('form : input'). In essence, when the user clicks on any input in the form, it is focussed. When a user clicks out of the form from any input it is blurred, but, the blur does not get triggered between tabbing between inputs in the form itself.

Comment: @Mark Anderson - that is what the `$('body').live('click')` is for. Events will bubble up to the body node. However when you click or focus anything inside the `form` the `e.stopPropagation` call prevents the event from reaching the body.